# Getstream getting a 403 NotAllowedException error when getting the feed

Tags: permissions, feed, getstream-io

I'm trying to setup a demo where a user can get notification about what's going on in his workspace.
I've shaped this model with a *notification* feed of type `notification` and a *workspace* feed of type `flat`

Both user and workspace are identified in the getstream world by their IDs

The user's *notification* feed follows his workspaces's *workspace* feed.
Server side:

```
const client = stream.connect(apiKey, secret, appId)
const feed = client.feed('notification', userId).follow('workspace', workspaceId, (r, e) => console.log("result: ", r, "error: ", e))
```

Then in the app I want to subscribe to *notification* feed to get new notifications in realtime and also retrieve the last 5 notifications to show them in a dropdown (facebook style):

```
const streamClient = stream.connect(apiKey, token, appId)
notificationFeed = streamClient.feed('notification', userId)
subscription = notificationFeed.subscribe(handleNewEvents)
notificationFeed.get.get({mark_seen: true, limit: 5})
```

This last get Request is rising a 403 error:

```
{"detail":"You don't have permission to do this","status_code":403,"code":17,"exception":"NotAllowedException","duration":"0.10ms"}
```

what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you see the tutorial on this? https://getstream.io/docs/#notification-system

Note Step 3 and creating the readonly token. Is that what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

I generated a new client token for the app and this fixed the error

Comment: I saw the tutorial but didn't think that a readonly token could make any difference